# Why is this code, with display flex, justify-content center and align-item center not aligning the elements to the center horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am learning JS and one of the tasks I do - is to code simple JS, HTML and CSS oriented code just to help me learn JS and be able to create certain JS web elements and projects so that when I feel I have a good grasp on JS I can apply them to larger projects in the future.

Anyways, I am using:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
/* AND */
justify-content: center;
```

To the "body" in my CSS file. Shouldn't that make elements be displayed automatically in the center, Vertically and Horizontally? I do not have any other CSS rules that would mess with it. I don't think anyways.

However, if I inspect the element and go to the very top line of code - the HTML code that is:
`<html lang="en">`
and then (within Inspect Element still) add the following to the **element.style**
`height: 100%;`
As well as add it to the body tag which I declared in my CSS file.
`height: 100%;`

Poof, it works. It centers the elements to the center of the page vertically. It is already centered horizontally. Just not vertically until I add that code. But I don't think I should have to add a height of 100% to the
`<html lang="en"> element.style`
So what am I doing wrong exactly here? I am using VSCode and then previewing the HTML file with LifeServer extension. I am learning Flexbox - because I just recently started to taking coding serious with the hopes of eventually landing a job (after schooling online).

Here is my code, sorry for the long post. Just incredibly confused.

```css
body {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.arrows {
  height: 70px;
}


/* .left-arrow {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 50px;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <img src="images/left-arrow.svg" class="arrows arrow-left" alt="Left Arrow">
    <div class="frame">
      <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
    <img src="images/right-arrow.svg" class="arrows arrow-right" alt="Right Arrow">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>

<script src="slider.js"></script>
```

There is no code in the slider.js file. I haven't gotten that far yet.

I have tried changing multiple CSS classes height's from 100% AND 100vh. I am honestly not sure what is going on, I have gotten rid of some HTML elements as well as some CSS elements.

Comment: *But I don't think I should have to add a height of 100%*, but you do. By default most elements don't have the `height` property set and will grow based on its content. If you want the alignment to happen regardless of the size of the content, then you have to *explicitly* set the height.

Comment: Why do you think you should not specify 100% height? Even when you are thinking it is not vertically centered actually it is vertically centered within the available height. But if you are thinking it to bring in the viewport center then you have to specify the viewport height. It can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Oh ... The problem I had everytime I wanted to center something in the body ...

The problem is that your body `height` is not automatically set to 100% of the viewport height and if your content does not fill that height, you need to set it manually on the body like this:

```
body {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

"vh" is a unit for sizes and represents "Viewport Height". When we set the height of the body to 100vh, it basically means that the height of the body should be 100% of the viewport and its interesting to know that if you just simply set the height of the body to 100% it doesn't work! It may be a little confusing but I will explain it now. When you do this:

```
body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

It basically means that the height of the body should be 100% of the PARENT ELEMENT which is the html tag but its important to note that if you don't set height for the html tag, the height will be automatically set by the child elements.

I hope my explanation was good enough so that you could resolve your problem, let me know if you still had any problems

Comment: It could really be just this, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I did find that as an answer - but found it weird that I had to adjust the body height and the container height too 100%. Because the tutorial I am watching does not show him doing that at all.

Comment: @JonP - I'm happy that it fixed your problem